# Collision with tile corners/seams in 2D platformer

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, platformer, collision-resolution

There seems to be a lot of somewhat related questions answered already, but none I read answered my exact problem.

I have a 2D platformer whose world is made entirely out of tiles that are in a regular grid. When there is a collision, I just move the character to the position he was in prior to the collision and it works well enough for me.

The character can fly/slide in the world, so I also want to set the speed towards the collided tile to zero. **Here lies my problem.**

At the moment the only way to do this I can think of is to check the difference between the character position and the center of the tile. If (the absolute value of the) x-difference is greater, then it is a horizontal collision. If y-difference is greater, then it's a vertical one. However, as the character is sliding horizontally on tiles, from one tile to another, sometimes he stops at the seam of the tiles because momentarily the x-difference becomes a tiny bit greater than the y-difference (due to float inaccuracies I suspect). I don't know if it's possible to change this algorithm to fix this, or if I need a new one. Any algorithm will do, as long as it fulfills the "requirements" stated above.

If at all possible, I want to treat the x- and y-collisions identically, because the movement is not just walking horizontally.

Image illustration: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/URkoV.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxstz.png)

Comment: Is [this one of the questions](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/25052/11686) you read? If so, how does it not solve the problem? Unless I misunderstood the requirements, it seems to fit. For instance, [in the linked video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-D0PGdoDDY) I'm flying around within the world, and sliding along walls in every direction without getting stuck at seams.

Comment: I had not read that, but I don't think it is a solution for my problem. Elaboration: The problem occurs even when not moving diagonally. I suspect a key difference is that in my game there is momentum, so losing speed for even one step in physics is enough to ruin the experience.

Comment: I no longer have the test project I used for that answer, but it worked just as well under momentum - I simply set the X or Y component of velocity to zero when colliding with a wall, but seams between tiles were never a problem. In sum, it worked well in every situation I tested it. Also by moving diagonally, I meant any situation where the player is pushing into the wall while sliding. For instance, moving horizontally while acted upon by gravity would be considered moving diagonally too.

Comment: Good to know. I will try to investigate. In the mean time, I uploaded an illustration of the problem to the OP.

Comment: Applying the idea to your algorithm is simple. If I understood correctly, at the moment you have a velocity vector that you're applying to your object. You apply velocity as a vector by adding it to the position, detect collisions with tiles, if there's a collision you move back to the original position, and use the relative positions of the object and tiles to figure out in which direction the collision happened, so that you can cancel out the velocity in that direction. So there are borderline cases where this direction is figured out wrong. (Continued)

Comment: I think you may be able fix it by *not* trying to figure out in which direction you moved, by processing the move and collision in two steps, one for each axis. So you have a velocity vector, but you start by only applying the X component of velocity. If there's a collision you reset only the X component of the position. And you already know the move was horizontal, so you set velocity X to zero. Then you repeat the same step but for the Y component of velocity. Since each step is done separately, you already know if the collision was horizontal or vertical without comparison checks.

Comment: To the first of your 2 comments: yes, you understood correctly. The the second: that's very clever way of doing things and I do think it could work. However, I'm not sure if that's a bullet-proof solution, since the order in which axes are checked could affect the result. It's likely not an issue apart from large velocities or big time steps, but I would still prefer something that was "correct". Moreover, I would like to separate movement and collision checks instead of interleaving them. I will try your solution, but I'm still interested in hearing other suggestions. :)

Comment: You're right, I also had the same concerns as you when I came up with the solution. Therefore I tried testing it as much as I could, and found no problems, but I'm sure there might be some way to make it fail. I'd also prefer to keep movement and collision in two separate steps. Will keep an eye on this thread to see if there's an obvious solution.

Comment: I could think of one situation, http://i.imgur.com/JLRyq.png. Assuming the boxes are close enough and/or the time step is large enough, if you update y before x it could collide with the above box, even though in reality it should not (not sure if this is clear from the picture, but I tried to make it so that the boxes just barely avoid each other)

Comment: I also drew a picture that looked almost exactly like that 5 minutes ago. And you're right, it could fail in a situation like that. In practice though, results were quite good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a really common problem, and I'd be very surprised if it hasn't been answered several times already.

Short version of several potential fixes:

1) Ignore internal edges between tiles using flags.  For each tile, set a flag for each of its four sides indicating whether that side is external (adjacent to an empty cell) or not.  Then only do collision tests against edges that have the flag set.  So in your example, since the edge between the two floor tiles is an internal edge, you would not perform the x axis test against that edge.  There is a great series of articles by the N+ author on metanet that takes this technique a bit further, with working Flash demos.

2) Collapse external edges into a simplified set of lines.  This is a bit more complicated that the previous method, but can be more flexible.  Essentially, find all the external edges and convert them into line segments.  The find all line segments that share a vertex and have the same normal an merge them into a single line segment.  Then switch your collision detection to use AABB to line segment tests.  The result is that you won't have any internal edges to test against in the collision data structure.  Also, this makes it easier to add arbitrarily shaped tiles later.

3) A simple but error prone method is to just special case a lot of your collisions logic.  This is what some old school classic platformers did.  It's often sufficient to take the direction of movement and then do collision detection against the "most perpendicular" of the x or y axis, then do the other.  For instance, if the player is mostly moving horizontally, first do collision along the y axis and resolve, then against the x axis.  Include a small bit of tolerance.  Result will be that the player is pushed out of the floor enough that the problematic internal edge collision falls within the error tolerance and is ignored.

4) use hot spot collision detection.  This is what most old school platformers did.  I don't care for this method myself and it takes some work to explain (although it's very simple to implement), but Google can likely find a few articles on it for you.  You may find this method best suits your needs if youre aiming for simplicity.

Comment: What's your recommendation from the four methods (especially when both the tiles and the player are represented by AABBs)?

Comment: This looks very good! I'll test and report back.

Comment: Without more information on the game's specific need, I'd say that option 1 will give the best results for little effort.  I've used it before and have been fairly happy with it.  Still need a few game-specific tweaks to make it perfect.

Comment: I just implemented 1, it was easy to code and it works very well! However, I had also to check that the movement direction is such that it can collide. For example when "walking off" a tile I sometimes had a collision, since the side where I was walking to was empty. After adding the direction check, it seems to work flawlessly.